# C# string to Dictionary<string, List<string>> with LINQ

Tags: c#, string, linq, dictionary

Say I have a string like this:

```
string test = "A1:B1:C1, A2:B2:C2, A3:B3:C3"
```

How can I use LINQ to split it up and store it in a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`

as follows:

Key: A1 (`string`)
Value: B1 and C1 (`List<string>`)

Key: A2 (`string`)
Value: B2 and C2 (`List<string>`)

Key: A3 (`string`)
Value: B3 and C3 (`List<string>`)

Thanks guys.

Comment: Show us what you've tried, and explain what's wrong with your solution (errors, unexpected results, etc.). If it didn't work or didn't even compile, we expect you to show *some* effort.

Comment: Well I can;t say about linq but its pretty easy in a simple forloop...

Answer (score 3):

```
(from entry in test.Split(',')
 from item in entry.Split(':')
 select item).ToDictionary(i => i[0], i => new string[] { i[1], i[2] }.ToList());
```

(untested)

Comment: Boogart Linq looks so cool ,declarative programming... :) +1

Comment: What if there's less or more than two final items?

Comment: @It'sNotALie: the question suggests that there are always 2 items, and that's all I've got to go by. Otherwise, could use `i.Skip(1).ToList()`.

Comment: @KentBoogaart Better be safe than sorry ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
var dict = test.Split(',')
               .Select(x=>x.Trim().Split(':'))
               .ToDictionary(k=>k[0],v=>new List<string>(){v[1],v[2]});
```

Comment: What if there's less or more than two final items?

Answer (score 0):

This also handles more or less than 3 items.

```
test.Split(',').Select(s => s.Split(':'))
    .ToDictionary(e => e.FirstOrDefault(), e => e.Skip(1).ToList());
```